# Keep date format with datetime python

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

I'm trying to keep the format of a date after converting it to a datetime, and then splitting it into year/month/day.

I need my python code to read a start_date and an end_date as arguments, and then going through all these days and performing an operation (for the sake of this problem let's say just printing) for each day. The thing is, I want these dates to print in the input format, so if my command line is: `print_dates.py 2020-01-07 2020-01-10` then my code will print:

```
year: 2020, month: 01, day: 07
year: 2020, month: 01, day: 08
year: 2020, month: 01, day: 09
```

But if my input is `print_dates.py 2020-1-7 2020-1-10` this will print:

```
year: 2020, month: 1, day: 7
year: 2020, month: 1, day: 8
year: 2020, month: 1, day: 9
```

My code is the following, but this code gives the same output no matter what format the input date has.

```
start_date_dt = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
end_date_dt = datetime.strptime(end_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
n_days = int((end_date_dt - start_date_dt).days)
for n in rage(n_days):
    d = start_date_dt + timedelta(n)
    print("year: {}, month: {}, day: {}".format(d.year, d.month, d.day))
```

Comment: If your inputs are `2020-1-31 2020-2-10` how do you know if you're supposed to output `2020-1-31 2020-2-1 2020-2-2... 2020-2-10` or `2020-1-31 2020-2-01 2020-2-02... 2020-2-10`?

Comment: Both inputs should have the same format, in another case the code will raise an exception and stops.

Answer (score 0):

Detecting the format will be kind of tricky. There might be one somewhere, but I'm not aware of any libraries which parse a datestring into a format string (and in any case, you'll need more formatting options than strptime uses). If there aren't any you'll probably have to hand-roll your own parser for the cases you care about.

That said, if all you need to know is whether you have to zero-pad or not then consider something like the following:

```
if zero_pad:
    print("year: {:02d}, month: {:02d}, day: {:02d}".format(d.year, d.month, d.day))
else:
    print("year: {}, month: {}, day: {}".format(d.year, d.month, d.day))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this wouldn't work. I wrote print in order to make it easier to understand, but I'm actually calling a function with Parallel, so I can't add an if statement inside it.
`Parallel(n_jobs=n_days)(delayed(compose)( start_date + timedelta(n)) for n in range(n_days))`